# ScalaTest afterAll() being called after each test

Tags: scala, scalatest

**TLDR; In a ScalaTest spec that mixes in both `BeforeAndAfterAll` and `ParallelTestExecution`, `afterAll()` is being called after each test, then again after all of them. I only want the after all behaviour.**

I have a ScalaTest spec like this:

```
class TestSpec extends fixture.FunSpec with ShouldMatchers with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll with ParallelTestExecution {
   override def afterAll() = {
      println("afterAll")
   }

   describe("something") {
      it("should foo") {
         println("foo")
      }

      it("should bar") {
         println("bar")
      }
   }
}
```

The two tests want to share a fixture, then `afterAll()` should clean up the fixture. I've omitted the details of the fixture code as immaterial to this question.

Here's the output of my test:

```
foo
afterAll
bar
afterAll
afterAll
```

So `afterAll()` is being called after each test, then again after all of them. I only want it to be called after all tests.

Does anyone know why `afterAll()` is behaving like this?

**Update**

If I don't mix in `ParallelTestExecution`, my test behaves properly:

```
foo
bar
afterAll
```

Unfortunately, I actually want  `ParallelTestExecution`. Is there any way to have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a normal behavior since, to reduce the risk of concurrency clashes and bugs, `ParallelTestExecution` runs each test in its own instance of the Test class. Each one of your tests will be ran as a separate instance of `TestSpec`, this results in `beforeAll` and `afterAll` being executed for each instance.

However you can work around this (in order to get one `beforeAll` and one `afterAll` executed for all) using nested suites, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423337/doing-something-before-or-after-all-scalatest-tests) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

From the horse's mouth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731847/89509

Basically each test case will run as its own instance, which will each call `afterAll` once.